# when using tcp-inbound-gateway, socket is timing out response is sent to it

Tags: spring-integration

This is what my configuration is:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="myServer"
        type="server" port="${port}" deserializer="serializeDeserialize"
        serializer="serializeDeserialize" single-use="true"
        using-nio="true" so-linger="500"
        backlog="100" so-timeout="10000"
        lookup-host="false" />

    <bean id="serializeDeserialize"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayRawSerializer" />


    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="myGateway"
        connection-factory="myServer" request-channel="inputMessagechannel"
        error-channel="errorChannel" reply-timeout="10000"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inputMessagechannel"
        ref="messageReceiver" method="process" />
```

While service activator returns a response within a second and still I see that socket is closed.  Here is the log:

```
2015-03-14 11:48:15,806  WARN [pool-2-thread-1] (AbstractConnectionFactory.java:555) - Timing out TcpNioConnection 20124 : 101.222.165.210:46930:632ce959-35ca-4f8e-be7f-5be3ecc166b0
2015-03-14 11:48:17,155  INFO [pool-2-thread-14] (InputMessageReceiver.java:69) - Message from <payload printed here>
2015-03-14 11:48:17,156 ERROR [pool-2-thread-14] (TcpInboundGateway.java:105) - Connection not found when processing reply [Payload=RESPONSE][Headers={timestamp=1426313897156, id=2ae8bb69-859a-4632-ac13-1a52fa493e56, ip_tcp_remotePort=46930, ip_address=101.222.165.210, ip_hostname=101.222.165.210, ip_connectionId=101.222.165.210:46930:632ce959-35ca-4f8e-be7f-5be3ecc166b0}] for [Payload=[B@132509][Headers={timestamp=1426313897154, id=a0c2dfc9-d097-448e-bf4d-15465903cf0c, ip_tcp_remotePort=46930, ip_address=101.222.165.210, ip_hostname=101.222.165.210, ip_connectionId=101.222.165.210:46930:632ce959-35ca-4f8e-be7f-5be3ecc166b0}]
```

Any idea how to get this to work?  I guess `serializeDeserialize` has something to do with this because even before payload is sent to SA, connection is timed out or may be payload is forwarded when connection is timed out marking it as end of message :( So if this is the case, then please suggest any suitable serializeDerialize (the default ones provided are not suitable to use here as the message is delimited by ';' and only when response to first message is sent subsequent messages can be received.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).

The `ByteArrayRawSerializer` detects the end of stream by the peer closing the socket; you need to use a `ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer` configured to detect `;` as the terminating character.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try with this one but not sure if dserialize will work as it does not have any terminating character while responding to incoming socket stream.  Meanwhile, I did hack ByteArrayRawSerializer a bit by exiting from while loop when this terminating character is found and it has worked as response is sent before replyTimeout.

Comment: TCP is a stream; there is no structure imposed on the data. You will need a custom (de)serializer if you don't have a consistent/simple format to delimit messages from the stream with one of the provided classes.